# My Style Sheet Not Overriding Normalize.css <h1> Margin

Tags: css

I'm at a loss as to why my stylesheet is *not* overriding the margin values of `normalize.css`.

In the html, the order of the links to the style sheets is correct:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/2may.css">
```

In *normalize.css*, the *margin* for **h1** is set as follows:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0.67em 0;
}
```

With *my* stylesheet I am trying to override that:

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #ddd;
  padding: 0; 
  border: 0;
  margin: 0; 
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Thats because the `h1` selector has a higher specifitiy than just `*`

Comment: `* { }` I believe will not override anything if an element is given a style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More specific rules override general ones like `*`. That's why normalize.css is overriding that selector.

For example, if I have these two selectors, the more specific one is applied and in this case, it's `.foo#someId`:

```
.foo#someId { 
  color: red; 
}

.foo { color: blue; }
```

whereas if I have two of the same, the first one written is applied:

```
.foo{ color: red } //text will be red

.foo{ color: blue }
```

Here is a link to the spec for more information:

http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/cascade.html#cascade

Answer (score 2):

Because `h1` is more precise than `*`

You should read [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#specificity)

Examples:

```
*               /* a=0 b=0 c=0 -> specificity =   0 */
LI              /* a=0 b=0 c=1 -> specificity =   1 */
UL LI           /* a=0 b=0 c=2 -> specificity =   2 */
UL OL+LI        /* a=0 b=0 c=3 -> specificity =   3 */
H1 + *[REL=up]  /* a=0 b=1 c=1 -> specificity =  11 */
UL OL LI.red    /* a=0 b=1 c=3 -> specificity =  13 */
LI.red.level    /* a=0 b=2 c=1 -> specificity =  21 */
#x34y           /* a=1 b=0 c=0 -> specificity = 100 */
#s12:not(FOO)   /* a=1 b=0 c=1 -> specificity = 101 */
```

In your case just add :

```
margin: 0;
```

to your h1 declaration.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to override the `h1` styles in `normalize.css`, you may want to target the same selector in your CSS:

```
h1 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #ddd;
  padding: 0; 
  border: 0; 
  margin: 0;  /* this is the new one */
  text-decoration: none;
}
```